# why doesn't $f(x)=x^2$ map $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}^2$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm asked to construct a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}^2$. Why doesn't $f(x)=x^2$ map $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}^2$?

I can see that $1\rightarrow 1^2$,$2 \rightarrow 2^2$,$3\rightarrow 3^2,\dots$

Why I'm I wrong?

Comment: Do you know what $N^2$ means?

Comment: In general, $X^2 = \{ (a,b) \ | \ a, b \in X \}$. Hence $\mathbb{N}^2 \neq \{ n^2 \ | \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \}$

Comment: I find that disturbing, because $n\mathbb{N}$ are natural integer n multiples, so why for example wouldn't $\mathbb{N}^2$ be squares ?

Comment: @servabat: $\mathbb{N}^2 = \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is why.

Comment: @servabat: Because $X^2$ is the set of all functions from $\{0,1\}$ into $X$, which can be identified with $X\times X$. Moreover, not every set has a multiplicative structure on it. If you have an arbitrary set $X$, what is $x+y$ for $x,y\in X$? Remember that those might not be numbers, or vectors, or functions. Just random mathematical objects. Similarly what is $x\cdot y$ for $x,y\in X$? It has no specified meaning. So perhaps, before being disturbed, learn a bit more about the reasons for this notation.

Comment: @servabat Usually $X^2$ is shares abbreviation with $X \times X$, which is not considered the same notation as $nN$, but depending on your country and background, ymmv.

Comment: I think this is a great question. For those of us who never thought about it, the answer is obvious. But let's understand why people do think this way, because that is how we learn how the beauty of mathematics can be really understood by more people.

Comment: Well, I always used $\mathbb{N}^n$ for n-uplets but somehow this answer made me wonder why couldn't this also mean something else.

Answer (score 8):

$\mathbb{N}^2$ is the set of all pairs $(x,y)$ where $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$.
That is, $1^2, 2^2, \dots$ are not elements of $\mathbb{N}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

First we have that $\mathbb{N}^2 = \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} = \{(n,m) ; n \in \mathbb{N} \ \  \text{and}\ \ m\ \in \mathbb{N}\}$, for more about cartesian product check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) .

To give you a north, define

$$\begin{align} f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} &\to \mathbb{N} \\(m,n) &\mapsto 2^{m-1} (2n -1)\end{align}$$

Can you show why this is a bijection?